# Why does JavaScript aws-sdk ssm getParameter require permissions for all parameters instead of just the one I need?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-parameter-store

I'm using javascript in my aws lambda, it calls SSM getParameter and the execution role for the lambda has the proper permissions for the key I'm looking to get the value of.

Originally, I was getting this specific error:

```
ERROR   AccessDeniedException: User: arn:aws:sts::123456789:assumed-role/my-role/my-lambda is not authorized to perform: ssm:GetParameter on resource: arn:aws:ssm:us-east-1:123456789:parameter/my/parameter
```

The specific error made sense, so I corrected my policy, as I had accidentally put GetParameters instead of GetParameter. But now, I am getting this questionable error (note the * at the end):

```
ERROR   AccessDeniedException: User: arn:aws:sts::123456789:assumed-role/my-role/my-lambda is not authorized to perform: ssm:GetParameter on resource: arn:aws:ssm:us-east-1:123456789:*
```

This error does not make any sense to me. Why do I need to access every single parameter? I need only the one I'm asking for.

Here is the relevant code:

```js
const data = await ssm.getParameter({Name: 'my/parameter', WithDecryption: true}).promise();
```

And the permission policy (created in a CloudFormation template)

```yaml
MyLambdaRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      RoleName: my-role
      Description: my-role description
      Policies:
        - PolicyName: cloudwatch-access
          ...
        - PolicyName: parameter-store-access
          PolicyDocument:
            Statement:
              - Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - "ssm:GetParameter"
                Resource:
                  - !Sub "arn:aws:ssm:*:${AWS::AccountId}:parameter/my/parameter"
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service:
                - lambda.amazonaws.com
            Action:
              - 'sts:AssumeRole'
```

### Edit:

After changing the permission policy to match the error message, I am now experiencing this strange error:

```
ERROR   ValidationException: Parameter name: can't be prefixed with "ssm" (case-insensitive). If formed as a path, it can consist of sub-paths divided by slash symbol; each sub-path can be formed as a mix of letters, numbers and the following 3 symbols .-_
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like the solution was to prefix the parameter name with a '/'.

In my example, I used `{Name: 'my/parameter'}`
After using `{Name: '/my/parameter'}`, things seem to be working fine.

Talk about a senseless error message...